# Using Bootstrap: JS function stop working when nav bar is toggled

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have a simple JS Junction that stop working when the break point of my responsive website is activated (The nav var toggle/collapse at 768px, here is when the JS function stop working)

The HTML is:

```
<div class="mainFoto">
   <img id="bigImage" src="/fotosArticulos/12578.jpg">
</div>
<div class="misProductosFotos">
   <div class="foto" onclick="callImage('12578.jpg');"><img src="/Thumbs/12578.jpg"></div>
   <div class="foto" onclick="callImage('30643.jpg');"><img src="/Thumbs/30643.jpg"></div>
   <div class="foto" onclick="callImage('12656.jpg');"><img src="/Thumb/12656.jpg"></div> 
</div>
```

and the JS function is

```
function callImage(idImage) {
var imageUrl = '/fotosArticulos/'+idImage;
$('#bigImage').attr('src', imageUrl);
}
```

This simple does that when click on one thumb the JS change the SRC of id="bigImage"

Why this Function stop working and how fix it?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ sample would be helpful! Where have you defined the function? It needs to be $(document).ready(function(){})

Comment: @Mutant since the problem is only using bootstrap I don't see the way how I'd reproduce a jsfiddle.net example without the bootstrap libraries. The function not need to be defined on $(document).ready(function(){}) since this is just a stand alone function, it is invoked with the onclick event (anyway I declared as you said and I get the same behavior) I don't see the problem is in the function, since it work correctly when the browser is in full view, the problem looks that is on the bootstrap tool, since I only get the issue when the website get collapsed at the  768px

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help you.

**HTML**

```
<div class="mainFoto">
    <img id="bigImage" src="/fotosArticulos/12578.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="misProductosFotos">
    <div class="foto">
        <img src="/Thumbs/12578.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="foto">
        <img src="/Thumbs/30643.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="foto">
        <img src="/Thumbs/12656.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
 $('.foto').click(function() {
        $('#bigImage').attr('src', $(this).find('img').prop('src').replace('/Thumbs/', '/fotosArticulos/'));
    })
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WAQcH/)

Comment: Anil, This code has the same behavior than mine, work fine above the 768px but when the view port collapse under 768px the JS code stop working, it does not even show the Alert message.

Answer (score 0):

@anilkumar, do you think storing `$(this).find('img').prop('src').replace('/Thumbs/', '/fotosArticulos/')` in a variable might make things a little more human readable? Like so:

```
$('.foto').on('click', function() {
var changeSrc = $(this).find('img').prop('src').replace('/Thumbs/', '/fotosArticulos/');
$('#bigImage').attr('src', changeSrc);
})
```

@saymon, do you reckon you might be removing the `#bigImage` id from `.mainFoto > img` at the breakpoint? Or perhaps Bootstrap might be renaming the element id?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guys for all your support. The issue was that when the website collapsed and get responsive there was an invisible element that overlap the Thumbs icons, that is why they did not respond, I think I blend bootstrap too soon. Thanks again :)